# Add UINavigationController inside UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a UIToolbar (on bottom) and I want to add a UINavigationController with UINavigationBar inside.
But the UINavigationController is not displayed.

**MyViewController.m :**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int toolBarHeight = 44;
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [self.view bounds].size.height-toolBarHeight, [self.view bounds].size.width, toolBarHeight)];

    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:nil action:nil];
    toolBar.items = @[button];

    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];

    MyNavigationController *myNav = [[MyNavigationController alloc] init];

    [self addChildViewController:myNav];
}
```

Comment: You need to add viewController inside navigationController. `[[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding a view controller as a child view controller isn't enough. You also need to add the navigation controller's view as a subview of the container view controller's view.

```
[myNav willMoveToParentViewController:self];
myNav.view.frame = navFrame;  //Set a frame or constraints
[self.view addSubview:myNav.view];
[self addChildViewController:myNav];
[myNav didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

See [the View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/) for more details.

Comment: I am doing the same thing, however the height and width of the Nav controller is not as per the frame I set. The origin point is correct though. Can you help?

Comment: Usually this is related to Auto Layout, not the view controller nesting. You may need to add constraints in code and make sure `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to NO. If you're using springs and struts, make sure you add those before you add the view to the parent view.

Comment: Initially I was creating a `UINavigationController` programmatically and adding it. I resolved the issue by creating a Container view with the help of IB and connecting it with my UINavigationController. No code added at all, everything done through IB and it works perfect.

Comment: I had the same problem as @Sam with the frame height/width.  In IB, I created a dummy `UIView` of the size I want and then copy it with `mynav.view.frame = parentvc.ncplace.frame`.  Xcode says the frame is as expected but it displays wrong.  Reading the value back looks correct but if I read it back in `viewDidAppear`, it has changed.  Maybe because I'm locked in Landscape.  I can make it work by setting the frame in *that* method but then the appearance animation isn't as nice.  Instead, I do these steps in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and re-layout, careful not to recurse.  That works for me.

Comment: Small detail: you don't send the [myNav willMoveToParentViewController:self] message. -[UIViewController addChildViewController:] will send the message. Conversely, when removing a child view controller, you need to send [navController willMoveToParentViewController:nil]. Then -removeFromParentViewController will send [navController didMoveToParentViewController:nil].

Answer (score 1):

For swift 5

```
let childNavController = UINavigationController()
parrentVC.addChild(childNavController)
parrentVC.view.addSubview(childNavController.view)
//Add constraints or frame for childNavController here.
childNavController.didMove(toParent: parrentVC)
```