# Android fragments analog in iOS's swift

Tags: android, ios, swift, android-fragments

I'm making my first steps in Swift (3 days into it) and need something like Android's fragments

What I need to do :

have some views in xibs with it's own controllers and inflate them to some view container so they could fill all the container.

For example, I have a menu that will be in a left side of the screen on an iPad, and on iPhone this menu will be hidden in a drawer. By tapping on a menu item I inflate needed Fragment into a container that in the case of iPad takes 3/4 of the right side of the screen and in the case of iPhone it takes full screen.

With such approach I don't have to worry about where my Fragment view is showing, what part of a screen (or may be, the entire screen) it is occupying as it is a separate Fragment with it's own controller that can be substituted (or stacked) with another fragments and if I want to go backstack , previous Fragment will come in focus

Is there such an analog for iOS or how can I implement this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For implementing something analogous to fragments, you must use Container View in your View Controller with childViewControllers being populated inside it.

Documentation: [Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

You can find the 'Container View' element in the object Library of your Interface Builder in Xcode.

[image: Container view]

Also, you can create the new view controller that you want to add it through code as follows:

**Obj-C code:**

```
//To add child VC
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
    [self addChildViewController:content];                 
    content.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    [self.containerView addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          
}

//To remove child VC
- (void) hideContentController: (UIViewController*) content
{
    [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil];  
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];            
    [content removeFromParentViewController];      
}
```

Comment: Stacked in the sense? If you want to stack VCs inside the Container view then you would instead have to use a UINavigationController in between like mentioned here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778700/add-uinavigationcontroller-inside-uiviewcontroller

Comment: I mean , I can go back from this fragment to previous if needed

Comment: Yes. You would have to call popViewController on the UINavigationViewController instance present in your Container View to do that, as it would be maintaining the VC stack in the container.