# How to stop memory leak in UIView Container UIViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, heap-memory

I have a problem with the memory of the phone. Im trying to do something like android Fragments, so I have a container view and when I need to change the view, I only set the UIViewController in the container, but every time I change the container view, the memory heap increase a lot, so in 8 clicks the memory on the iPhone goes to 640mb. How can I remove the viewControllers in the memory? 
this is my code:

```
 private var activeViewController : UIViewController?{
    didSet {
      removeInactiveViewController(inactiveViewController:oldValue)
        updateActiveViewController()
           }
 }
private func removeInactiveViewController(inactiveViewController: UIViewController?){
    if let inactiveVC = inactiveViewController {
        inactiveVC.willMove(toParent: nil)
        inactiveVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        view controller
        inactiveVC.removeFromParent()
    }
}

private func updateActiveViewController(){
    if let activeVC = activeViewController {
        var duration = 0
        addChild(activeVC)
        activeVC.view.frame = fragmentContainer.bounds
        fragmentContainer.addSubview(activeVC.view)
        activeVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}

@IBAction func clickSearchs(_ sender: Any) {
    if (statusFragments != 1  && statusFragments != 0){
        prevStatusFragments = statusFragments
        statusFragments = 1
        imgSearch.isSelected = true
        imgNotif.isSelected = false
        imgRecord.isSelected = false
        imgProfile.isSelected = false
        imgOptions.isSelected = false
        if (mapViewController != nil) {
            print("Ya existia")
            mapViewController!.removeFromParent()
            mapViewController = nil
        }
        mapViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
            "MapContainerViewController")
        activeViewController = mapViewController
    } else {

    }

}

@IBAction func clickNotifs(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Hizo click en notificaciones")
    if (statusFragments != 2){

        prevStatusFragments = statusFragments
        statusFragments = 2
        imgSearch.isSelected = false
        imgNotif.isSelected = true
        imgRecord.isSelected = false
        imgProfile.isSelected = false
        imgOptions.isSelected = false
        if (notifViewController != nil) {
            notifViewController!.removeFromParent()
            notifViewController!.removeFromParent()
            notifViewController = nil
        }
        notifViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationsContainerViewController")
        activeViewController = notifViewController
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android fragments analog in iOS's swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084029/android-fragments-analog-in-ioss-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Your current code looks good, please check if there is a retain cycle in the `MapContainerViewController` or `NotificationsContainerViewController`. 
I recommend you to check all closures and variables defined in the view controllers.